# Magento 2 checkout without processing payment

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I'm looking for a way to use **Magento 2** without the payment processing functionality, but instead just keep the details of the order within the backend where it will be processed off-line via direct communication with customer. Are there any easy ways of accomplishing this? I know one option is to enable **COD** for orders - but I'm looking for something a bit more elegant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payments are tightly coupled into Magento checkout. Quote, orders, billing address - all of these use payment.
You might create a custom payment method that is based on Cash on Delivery - just with a different name/comment. Additionally, you can hide payment input field, so the Customer is not distracted by one radio button.